# Passing wrong data type to partial view model. How do I fix?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, linq

I know what I'm doing wrong but don't know how to fix it, particularly on the LINQ side. As you can see, I am querying my data into a list but my model is expecting "ProfileModelData". How do I fix this so everything aligns?

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult _ProfilePartial(string Id)
    {
        ProfileModel model = new ProfileModel();
        string un = Id;
        model.pdata = (from p in db.Users
                       where p.userid == un
                       select new ProfileModelData { lastname = p.lastname }
                        ).ToList();
        return PartialView("_ProfilePartial", model.pdata);
    }
```

Partial view:

```
 @model MyApp.Models.ProfileModelData

 <form id="EnrollForm" action="/MyView/SaveProfile" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

 <table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <h3>Required Information</h3>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>E-Mail Address*</td>
        <td>
            <span class="NoWrap">
                <input class="JobApplyInput FormReq" name="form_email1" id="form_email1" value="@Model.lastname" />
                <label id="Req_Join_Email" for="form_email1">
                    @Html.Partial("_RequiredFieldPartial")
                </label>
            </span>
        </td>
```

Model classes:

```
public class ProfileModelData
{
    public string lastname { get; set; }
}

public class ProfileModel
{
    public List<ProfileModelData> pdata { get; set; }
}
```

Please ignore the fact that "lastname" is going into the "email" input. I am just trying to get it to work in concept right now.

Comment: why arent u accepting `ProfileModel` as model for view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `First` to get single result , you already have a List, use `First` and return a single `ProfileModelData`

```
return PartialView("_ProfilePartial", model.pdata.First());
```